# Azure database for postgresql: change the owner of a table without using the super user

Tags: permissions, database, azure, postgresql, user

I'm working on a PostgreSQL v10 Database created in Azure. This database has several users including:

- **myuser**: user used by a web application. Has limited powers;
- **myadmin**: admin user created by azure used to create new users and databases;
- **azure_superuser**: super user created by azure whose password I don't know and cannot use;

With the user epadmin I created a new table and now I would like to change the owner of this table like this:

`ALTER TABLE public.mytable OWNER TO myuser;`

However, this returns the following error:

`SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be member of role "myuser"`

How can I change the owner of a table without using Azure super user?